# Is it possible to integrate Looker Studio with websites without keeping it public, to preserve data?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, looker-studio, google-cloud-iam, identity-management

I'm analyzing whether Looker Studio is a good option to use on websites.
The user authenticates on the website, and should see some dashboards.
These dashboards cannot have open public access, to preserve personal and sensitive data.
Looker Studio meets this demand?

PS: I have no interest in Google's other product, Looker (without Studio in the name)

I try follow the documentation, but it has no information about.
https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7450249